C++ while loop fails when integer has more than 10 digits
I have been trying to make a program that only allows users to process if the enter a 16 digit number.
here's my question why is does the while loop fail when when the input has more than 10 digits
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>


int getnum();
int intvalid(std::istream&cin);


int main(){
int number = getnum();
std::cout << number;
    return 0;
}

int intvalid(std::istream&cin){
    
    int choice;
    int digits;

    // problem 
    while (!(std::cin >> choice)){
        std::cout << "try again \n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }


    while(choice>0){
        digits++;
        std::cout << digits;
        choice = choice/10;
    }
    std::cout << digits;
    return digits;
}


int getnum(){
    std::cout << "Enter a Number (max 16 digits):\n";

    while (intvalid(std::cin) <= 16){
        std::cout << "try again \n";
    }


    return -1;
}   



int is 32-bit or 64-bit, it is not able to hold arbitrarily large numbers. Since you are only counting the digits, why use int at all, you can just use ordinary string and verify the content and length?

Please also provide some sample input to reproduce your issue, e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/359jKMrq6 . Then just debug your code, you will see that 16-digit numbers will not fit into int type. But std::uint64_t will be enough.

@Quimby -- int must be able to represent values in the range -32767 through 32767, which fits in 16 bits. It can be larger, of course, but it is not required to be 32 or 64 bits.

std::string can hold more digits than any human user wants to type. Your code uses cin to parse a sequence of characters / digits as an int then decomposes that int into digits. Using std::string  for the user input makes this much simpler. And if you need the int you can still get it later

What is the value of std::numeric_limits<int>::max() on your platform? My guess is that it has the value 2147483647, which is not sufficient to represent a 16-digit number.

If you use std::stoi instead of std::istream::operator >> in order to convert a string to an integer, then an exception will be thrown if the number is not in the representable range of an int.

This kind of thing is a very common "discover that a sequence of digits can also be viewed as a string" exercise.

I agree with @Quimby 's comment, maybe you'd better use a string... But if you really want to directly cin an (integral) number, you could use an (unsigned) specific type, or unsigned long long could work (with limitations) as follows
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int getnum();
unsigned long long  valid(std::istream&cin);

int main(){
    unsigned long long max = -1;
    std::cout<<"max Ulonglong = "<<max<<std::endl;//above will result in an error in your cin
    int number = getnum();
    
    std::cout << number<<std::endl;// well that'll be -1...
    return 0;
}

int intvalid(std::istream&cin){
    
    unsigned long long choice;
    int  digits;

    // problem 
    while (!(std::cin >> choice)){
        std::cout << "try again 1\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    while(choice>0){
        digits++;
        std::cout << digits;
        choice = choice/10;
    }
    std::cout << "=> "<<digits<<" digits"<<std::endl;
    return digits;
}

int getnum(){
    std::cout << "Enter a Number (max 16 digits):\n";

    while (intvalid(std::cin) <= 16){
        std::cout << "try again 2\n";
    }
    return -1;
}   

